# Visual Studio 2022 - Dialog not scaling, text unreadable

Tags: visual-studio, dialog

Dell XPS15 9520, Windows 11.

I'm using 2 sizes of monitor (the 15 inch XPS monitor & Dell 24 inch models), with resolutions of 3840 x 2400 and 1920 x 1080 respectively.

I'm developing an SSIS package in VS 2022.The Configure Connection Manager dialogs are not displaying correctly.

I've tried changing the screen resolutions & scale, but neither of these options work -  see example image. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rbeF.jpg)